# 国 - The 2 ways to pronounce

Tags: pronunciation

I know there are `音読み` and `訓読み`.

In case of 国, but has 2 way to pronounce: `国{くに}` vs `国{こく}`.

When to use which?

Comment: You are going to need to give more context to make the question genuinely answerable but the basic answer is that the word is pronounced コク or in sino-Japanese compounds. When standing alone, it is generally くに. Here's a [list of some common words](http://kakijun.jp/page/0847200.html)

Comment: very good question.

Comment: Do you plan to ask this question for every kanji? What did you learn from  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28371 ?

Comment: Do you know that 音読み is the copy of old Chinese pronunciation, and 訓読み is the translation into original Japanese. Generally, only either 訓読み or 音読み is used in a word. Please clarify what is your question with some examples or some sources.

Comment: @oals I ask again for this char because I can't tell which is the `音読み`, because neither of them pronounce similar to the character in Chinese.

Comment: @virmaior I see, that's a good website, according to the website, I think `こく` is the `音読み`.

Comment: If you look up a kanji in a kanji dictionary, it lists the kanji's 音読み in katakana and 訓読み in hiragana. (And sometimes the dictionary even includes 名乗り but that's irrelevant.)

Comment: @oals Ok, I never bought a dictionary, but it seems the website provided by `virmaior` is good enough.

Comment: @EricWang Paste your kanji into [wwwjdic's kanji lookup](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1B) for this sort of thing. Pasting 国 there returns [音] コク  [訓] くに

Comment: @oals The site is cool!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When 国 is used as a part of idiom like 米国, it's pronounced こく like 米国(べいこく). When it's used alone, it's pronounced くに.

Comment: Why has it been down-voted?